# How to use str.replace() in this case in Python?

Tags: python, replace

Expression example:

```
"abcddomain_rgz.png"
"djhajhdomain_rgb1.png"
```

Want to replace `domain*.png` in above expression with `"domain.json"`.

Answers:

```
"abcddomain.json"
"djhajhdomain.json"
```

Comment: You may want to look into regex. The string class doesn't do pattern matching. Although you can do it without regex if you just look for the start and end tokens and handle it yourself.

Comment: I agree. There's this way of doing it. However, I'm unsure if it handles all cases. `ln = "abcddomain_rgz.png"`. `''.join(list(ln)[:ln.find('domain')+len('domain')])+'.json'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical case of regex as mentioned in the comment section. Since you do not know the exact length of the string to be replaced right after `domain` until `.png`, you need to use a regular expression to perform that replacement.

Python provides you with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module, which you can use its [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function to perform the replace:

```
import re

string = "djhajhdomain_rgb1.png"

result = re.sub("domain(.*).png", "domain.json", string)

print(result)
```

This will return:

```
djhajhdomain.json
```

Answer (score 0):

use python regex instead (`re package`):

`re.sub(r'domain.*\.png$', r"domain.json", 'djhajhdomain_rgb1.png')`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here would be regex.

```
x = "djhajhdomain_rgb1.png"
y = "djhajhdomain.json"

import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\w+domain')
ext = '.json'

match = re.match(pattern, x).group(0)
result = match+ext

assert result == y
```

1. import regex
2. compile a pattern to search in string. (Note here that the pattern will only accept alphanumerals and/or underscore before the literal string "domain")
3. set a pre-defined string extension
4. use the pattern compiled to match the string
5. concatenate the result
6. confirm that your result matches your desired output